# NTLM authentication scheme selected error

Tags: java, web-services, exchange-server, exchange-server-2010

I am developing a application in Java to get email attachments from exchange server (version 10), i have windows 7 (32bit) pc. My code is compiling successfully but giving error at run time, saying-

```
May 20, 2013 5:58:46 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.auth.AuthChallengeProcessor selectAuthScheme
INFO: NTLM authentication scheme selected
May 20, 2013 5:58:47 PM org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector processWWWAuthChallenge
INFO: Failure authenticating with NTLM <any realm>@autodiscover.mydomain.com:443
```

and my code is -

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010);
    ExchangeCredentials credentials;
    credentials = new WebCredentials("myuser", "mypwd","mydomain");
    service.setCredentials(credentials);
    service.autodiscoverUrl("user@domain.com");
```

How to solve this NTLM authentication error?

Answer (score 0):

Enable Trace : `service.setTraceEnabled(true);`
Are you sure your Exchange version is 2010 ? use [this](https://superuser.com/questions/304461/how-can-i-detect-what-exact-version-of-exchange-server-i-connect-to-with-outlook) guide to check

also try removing `service.autodiscoverUrl("user@domain.com");`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an incorrect order of auth preferences.
I just changed them by editing the code.
I'm using EX_2007_SP3.

In `microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.HttpClientWebRequest:prepareConnection()` and `prepareAsyncConnection()` methods, I changed the auth preference order

from,

```
authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);
authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.BASIC);
authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.DIGEST);
```

to,

```
authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.BASIC);
authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.NTLM);
authPrefs.add(AuthPolicy.DIGEST);
```

And it is still working :) 
I have seen some of developers use NEGOTIATE too.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there a way to select a different AuthPolicy (e.g. SPNEGO) instead modifying the code?